# Neo4j cluster: How to designate master?

Tags: neo4j

I've just read through Neo4j's tutorial on creating a cluster (link at bottom), but no information is given regarding which node is designated as the 'master', or how this is done.

Let's say I'm working with the first example, where there are a total of three nodes installed on three separate machines. How would I make one the master?

If any part of my question is mistaken, please let me know and I will be quick to edit.

Here's that link:
[neo4j manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/ha-setup-tutorial.html)

Comment: The master is most probably the machine that first starts up.  Later on there might be an master re-election.

Comment: How could I go about identifying the master at any given time?

Comment: I later found that there is a specific URL you can visit in the neo4j web console which will show you the status of every node -- including its master/slave status: http://<your_ip>:7474/webadmin/#/info/org.neo4j/High%20Availability/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can read in the documentation, you can only set a master in advance if all other nodes in the cluster have the *ha.slave_only* property set to true. However I would advise not to do this as your cluster needs at least one other non-slave_only node to elect as new master in case the elected master goes down.

Identifying the master can be done via the HA REST endpoints. You can find all the info at http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/ha-rest-info.html